# Create MYSQL query with relative date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query that I update every month, and would like to have one that automatically update.
The current query is :

```
SELECT SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:59:59') AS SEPTEMBER,
       SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value > '2018-10-01 23:59:59') AS OCTOBER,
       SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value > '2018-11-01 23:59:59') AS NOVEMBER
FROM simp_posts p INNER JOIN
     simp_postmeta pm
     ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND
      p.post_status IN ('wc-active', 'wc-pending-cancel')
```

The result of that query look like :

```
September    October    November 
242          227         214
```

**Every month I change the date after "pm.meta_value > " and the AS.
What I would like is replace this hardcoded dates with :**

```
first day of next month (+1) at 23:59:59 AS MMMM (next month in all letters)
first day of next month (+2) at 23:59:59 AS MMMM (next month in all letters)
first day of next month (+3) at 23:59:59 AS MMMM (next month in all letters)
```

Is it possible?

Thank you, I hope I have been clear.

Comment: In order to dynamically name the columns in a query, you have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Will you be running this query directly in a mysql client? Like a Mysql Workbench or similar?

Comment: @codisfy I will use it in PHPmyadmin

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok So I haven't tried this but I believe it should work

```
SET @firstMonthDate = DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
SET @firstMonthName = UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(@firstMonthDate, '%M'));

SET @secondMonthDate = DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
SET @secondMonthName = UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(@secondMonthDate, '%M'));

SET @thirdMonthDate = DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
SET @thirdMonthName = UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(@thirdMonthDate, '%M'));

SET @query = concat("SELECT SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value >= ",@firstMonthDate,") AS ",@firstMonthName,",
       SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value >= ",@secondMonthDate,") AS ",@secondMonthName,",
       SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value >= ",@thirdMonthDate,") AS ",@thirdMonthName,"
FROM simp_posts p INNER JOIN
     simp_postmeta pm
     ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND
      p.post_status IN ('wc-active', 'wc-pending-cancel')");

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

So we get the next three months names and date into variables and then create a query string from it and then execute a stmt.

I changed the part where you compare with  23:59:59 > `date`, but I believe it should still work the same. 
If it gives any error, I believe it should be something related to a missing quote or something, which you should be able to debug.

Hope it works.
Do let me know the results.

Comment: thank you for your help. The answer I get is in the right format with the dynamic names but the numbers are incorrect, they are all the same . I tried removing "=" after "pm.meta_value >" but still got the same result.

Comment: @Jon your question has `> '2018-10-01 23:59:59') AS SEPTEMBER,` (month september is 9, you have mentioned 10) is that the reason for different numbers?

Comment: no sorry, the issue right now, is that the 3 numbers are the same, indicating that the timeframe isnt working

Comment: Can you try doing `select @query` and  comment the last two lines and see the raw query. Maybe I missed something, you can figure that out once you see the raw query.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure to understand what you mean by `select @query`

Comment: if you do `select @query` instead of the last two lines `PREPARE stmt FROM @query;EXECUTE stmt;`, if will output the query created and then you can see where the issue lies.

Comment: ok I found the issue, thank you so much ! I did what you asked and got that

`SELECT SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value >= 2018-09-02) AS SEPTEMBER,
      SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value >= 2018-10-02) AS OCTOBER,
      SUM((pm.meta_value = '0' AND p.post_status = 'wc-active') or pm.meta_value >= 2018-11-02) AS NOVEMBER
FROM simp_posts p INNER JOIN
    simp_postmeta pm
    ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_schedule_end' AND
     p.post_status IN ('wc-active', 'wc-pending-cancel')`

Comment: I needed to add single quote (') around the date in the query before/after the double quotes (").

Comment: Yes,  I knew that I would have missed a quote or something as I was not able to test it myself. Glad it worked